# How to search in multiple hashes for a specific keyword?

Tags: redis

I would like to know if there is a possibility to search multiple hashes for a specific keyword in Redis?

Suppose, I have 1000 hashes with [ user:1....., user:2....., user:3.....] and in these hashes I have multiple fields as [firstname, lastname, age, idnumber ....].
Now, I would like to search for all the users with "idnumber" starting with '111'?

Is it feasible in Redis.

Similar SQL command (for if my understanding was not clear), I would like to perform
"select * from users where idnumber like '111%';

Regards,
Piyush

I tried HSCAN but tht only works for a single hash -- I believe

Answer (score 1):

Redis does not have this capability out of the box. [RediSearch](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/) is a module that extends Redis to add it. The easiest way to get RediSearch is to install [Redis Stack](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/install/).

You can use it to create indices:

```bash
redis.local> FT.CREATE user:index ON HASH PREFIX 1 user:
  SCHEMA firstName TAG lastName TAG age NUMERIC idNumber TAG
```

And then search on them:

```bash
redis.local> FT.SEARCH user:index "@idNumber:{ 111* }"
```

RediSearch is a big topic but hopefully this is enough to point you in a useful direction.